# system("pause") for Linux g++ C++

Tags: c++, g++

In windows when compiling, system("pause")  works, what is the equivalent in linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works on windows and linux/unix:

```
std::cout << "Press \'Return\' to end." << std::endl;
std::cin.flush();
std::cin.get();
```

The first `std::cin.flush()` clears the input que, the next command waits for an input.

Comment: I'm getting this: std::istream {aka class std::basic_istream<char>}’ has no member named ‘flush’

Comment: Can you try to use `std::cin.flush()`.

Comment: I am using `using namespace std` . & tried your way too. But no improvement.